# How can I fix evicted libraries and ambiguous reference error in Scala (Akka 2.4.0)?

Tags: scala, akka

I have code that uses the new Akka 2.4.0.  Apparently I've got some libs that are compiled with earlier versions, so I get the warnings/errors shown.

Most problematic, I get an ambiguous reference problem shown below.

OK, so the compiler is warning me (I think) that it's bumped older Akka versions in favor of 2.4.0, then it's confused about akka.pattern.ask.

What should I do about it?

My output is below:

```
> test:compile
[info] Compiling 5 Scala sources to /Users/wmy965/git/hello/common/target/scala-2.11/test-classes...
[error] /Users/wmy965/git/hello/common/src/test/scala/common.test.service/FacilitiesTests.scala:16: ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
[error] both method ask in trait AskSupport of type (actorSelection: akka.actor.ActorSelection, message: Any, sender: akka.actor.ActorRef)(implicit timeout: akka.util.Timeout)scala.concurrent.Future[Any]
[error] and  method ask in trait AskSupport of type (actorSelection: akka.actor.ActorSelection, message: Any)(implicit timeout: akka.util.Timeout)scala.concurrent.Future[Any]
[error] match expected type ?
[error] import akka.pattern.ask._
[error]                     ^
[error] /Users/wmy965/git/hello/common/src/test/scala/common.test.service/FacilitiesTests.scala:43: value ? is not a member of akka.actor.ActorRef
[error] Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.
[error]             val result = Misc.await(harness.facilities.mongoControl ? MongoAction({ mongo =>
[error]                                                                     ^
[error] two errors found
[error] (common/test:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed Oct 23, 2015 5:57:17 PM
> evicted
[info] Updating {file:/Users/wmy965/git/hello/}hello...
[info] Updating {file:/Users/wmy965/git/hello/}common...
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12.1 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang.modules#scala-xml_2.11;1.0.4 ...
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies.
[warn] Here are some of the libraries that were evicted:
[warn]  * com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor_2.11:(2.3.12, 2.3.7) -> 2.4.0 (caller: com.cof:common_2.11:reactive2_a6d8f9, com.typesafe.akka:akka-stream-experimental_2.11:1.0, co.blocke:laterabbit_2.11:0.3, com.typesafe.akka:akka-slf4j_2.11:2.4.0, com.thenewmotion.akka:akka-rabbitmq_2.11:1.2.4)
[info] Here are other libraries that were evicted:
[info]  * org.slf4j:slf4j-api:(1.7.7, 1.6.0) -> 1.7.12 (caller: com.bionicspirit:shade_2.11:1.7.Z, org.mongodb:casbah-core_2.11:2.8.2, org.mongodb:casbah-gridfs_2.11:2.8.2, org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.7, com.typesafe.akka:akka-slf4j_2.11:2.4.0, org.mongodb:casbah-commons_2.11:2.8.2, org.mongodb:casbah-query_2.11:2.8.2)
[info]  * org.mongodb:casbah_2.11:2.8.0 -> 2.8.2 (caller: com.cof:common_2.11:reactive2_a6d8f9, co.blocke:scalajack_mongo_2.11:4.4.1)
[info]  * org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:2.11.0 -> 2.11.7 (caller: co.blocke:scalajack_2.11:4.4.1, org.monifu:monifu-core_2.11:0.7.0)
[info]  * org.joda:joda-convert:1.2 -> 1.7 (caller: com.github.nscala-time:nscala-time_2.11:1.0.0, co.blocke:scalajack_2.11:4.4.1)
[info]  * org.scala-lang:scala-library:(2.11.0, 2.11.5, 2.11.4) -> 2.11.7 (caller: com.bionicspirit:shade_2.11:1.7.Z, com.github.nscala-time:nscala-time_2.11:1.0.0, com.typesafe.akka:akka-http-experimental_2.11:1.0, com.typesafe.akka:akka-stream-experimental_2.11:1.0, co.blocke:laterabbit_2.11:0.3, org.mongodb:casbah-gridfs_2.11:2.8.2, co.blocke:scalajack_2.11:4.4.1, com.typesafe.akka:akka-slf4j_2.11:2.4.0, org.monifu:monifu-core_2.11:0.7.0, org.mongodb:casbah-core_2.11:2.8.2, com.cof:common_2.11:reactive2_a6d8f9, com.typesafe.akka:akka-http-core-experimental_2.11:1.0, com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor_2.11:2.4.0, org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:2.11.7 (), org.mongodb:casbah_2.11:2.8.2, com.typesafe.akka:akka-parsing-experimental_2.11:1.0, org.mongodb:casbah-commons_2.11:2.8.2, org.mongodb:casbah-query_2.11:2.8.2, co.blocke:scalajack_mongo_2.11:4.4.1, com.thenewmotion.akka:akka-rabbitmq_2.11:1.2.4)
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12.1 ...
[info] Done updating.
[success] Total time: 1 s, completed Oct 23, 2015 5:57:30 PM
```

Comment: You probably want to track down which libraries are depending on the older version of Akka and upgrading them.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid ambiguity, you can either add `sender()` or `ActorRef.noSender` - depends on the context. Or add a timeout `mongoControl.ask(MongoAction({...}))(1.second)`